# Custom ParamConverter doesn't work (doesn't give error but return isn't what it should)

Tags: 8, routes

I'm learning Drupal8 (for the first time, no Drupal7 or previous knowledge) on a local Vagrant VM and have come up against this little problem. I'm sorry if it's kind of a noob question but I wasn't able to solve it and also couldn't find any specific hepful info out there.

I can access my route ("http://172.28.128.10/drupal-project/web/policeman/7") and no error is shown, but this is what my navigator (Chrome) displays:

```
plateNumber = $plate_number; } public function getPlateNumber() { return $this->plateNumber; } }
```

This is kinda weird in the sense that it seems like Drupal is having trouble with its internal calls but I don't quite understand why it's returning that and displaying it instead of throwing some kind of exception.

I know the routing works with other controllers I've created that don't use custom ParamConverters like "http://172.28.128.10/drupal-project/web/hello/3" which returns just fine the name of the user with said ID. Don't know if knowing other routes work is relevant for you.

ow_hello.routing.yml:

```
ow_hello.policeman:
  path: '/policeman/{policeman}'
  defaults:
    _controller: \Drupal\ow_hello\Controller\PolicemanController::view
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
  options:
    parameters:
      policeman:
        type: policeman
```

ow_hello.services.yml:

```
services:
  ow_hello.policeman_param_converter:
    class: Drupal\ow_hello\Routing\PolicemanParamConverter
    tags:
    - { name: paramconverter }
```

Policeman.php:

```
<?

namespace Drupal\ow_hello;

class Policeman {

  private $plateNumber;

  public function __construct($plate_number) {
    $this->plateNumber = $plate_number;
  }

  public function getPlateNumber() {
    return $this->plateNumber;
  }

}
```

PolicemanParamConverter.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ow_hello\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Drupal\ow_hello\Policeman;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

class PolicemanParamConverter implements ParamConverterInterface {

  public function applies($definition, $name, Route $route) {
    return !empty($definition['type']) && $definition['type'] == 'policeman';
  }

  public function convert($value, $definition, $name, array $defaults) {
    return new Policeman($value);
  }

}
```

PolicemanController.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ow_hello\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\ow_hello\Policeman;

class PolicemanController extends ControllerBase {

  public function view(Policeman $policeman) {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello my plate number is: @plate_number', ['@plate_number' => $policeman->getPlateNumber()]),
    ];
  }

}
```

Comment: If it's not a copy and paste error, Policeman.php is missing <?php in the first line.

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb. Thank you very much for pointing that out! I blame phpStorm, after all it should do all my work for me (????) xD Indeed now it works just fine, thanks!!

Comment: What should I do about the question in a case like this? Can I somehow close it? Do I respond to myself with the solution and mark it as solved? Do I leave it as is?